# Snowflake - How to add start_date based on the first_published_at column

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I need to calculate start and end date columns based on the **first_published_at** and **published_at** columns.

At the moment my table looks like this:

[image]

I got that result from this query:

```
select  uuid
  , first_published_at
, published_at
, published_at as start_date
, ifnull(lead(published_at, 1) over(partition by uuid order by published_at),to_date('2050-12-31')) as end_date
from base_posts
```

What I can't solve is how to add `first_published_at` as a first value in `start_date` column.

I hope that I was precise enough. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Please include source data as text and target or expected result.

Answer (score 0):

To get first value per group either `FIRST_VALUE` or `MIN` could be used:

```
SELECT *,
   FIRST_VALUE(start_date) OVER(PARTITION BY uuid 
                                ORDER BY published_at) AS first_published_at,
   MIN(start_date) OVER(PARTITION BY uuid) AS first_published_at2
FROM base_posts
```